# Reuse attribute value in XML document

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML file based on an XML Schema. The schema is not created by me so I cannot change it. Now I need to use the same attribute value in several places inside the XML file.

Is there a way to define something like macro for the value and use it for attribute values to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to define something like macro for the value and use it for attribute values to avoid duplication?

Sure; it's called a *general entity*.  Let us assume that you want all the attributes in the following XML to have the same value, and for changing that value to require changing only one place in the document, not five.

```
<doc>
  <a foo="ajdalkhf lkajh"/> 
  <b>
    <c bar="adadf">data here</c>
    <d baz="aadfa dadf">more data here</d>
  </b>
  <e baffle="aasdh dadf"/>
  <f gorp="alkhf dlkajhds"/>
</doc>


<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY cookie "ajdalkhf lkajh">
]>
<doc>
  <a foo="&cookie;"/> 
  <b>
    <c bar="&cookie;">data here</c>
    <d baz="&cookie;">more data here</d>
  </b>
  <e baffle="&cookie;"/>
  <f gorp="&cookie;"/>
</doc>
```

This answer assumes that you are not asking about reusing bits of the XSD schema document, but takes you at your word:  your question asks about providing the same attribute value in multiple places in an XML document.  If the answer provided by FroberOfBits is on-topic, this one will not be, and vice versa.

Comment: I haven't heard about general entities. Can you provide a link with more details on them? This term is too generic to google. Are they from DTD? Can I use them in XML Schema based documents?

Comment: Odd; when I ask DuckDuckGo for "xml general entity" the first thirty-odd hits are all clearly relevant.  Yes, general entities are declared in DTDs.  And yes, they can be used in documents governed by XSD schemas; the entity-expansion step happens as part of parsing and is logically prior to and separate from XSD schema validation.

Comment: Time to switch to DuckDuckGo :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's some background on how to reuse components from XML schema](http://www.learn-xml-schema-tutorial.com/Reusing-Schema-Components.cfm).

If the schema you're trying to reuse from defines an attribute group, you can reuse that in your schema by using `ref` like this:

`<xs:attributeGroup ref="otherNS:NameOfAttributeGroup"/>`

This attribute group can be part of a `complexType` definition you invent.

In order for this to work, you need the schema you're reusing to define **globally** such an attribute group.  If it doesn't (local definition) then you're hosed and you can't refer to that attribute.

Comment: I do not create a schema. I need to create an XML document based on already existing XML schema (that I cannot change). No any attribute groups defined, actually the attribute is of primitive string type.